# Proving $n \ge 41, \dfrac{2^{\lfloor\sqrt{2n}-3\rfloor}}{n} \ge 1$ without using derivatives

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, inequality, induction

At the heart of the [standard proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate) for Betrand's Postulate is the inequality that for $n \ge 41$:

$$\dfrac{2^{\lfloor\sqrt{2n}-3\rfloor}}{n} \ge 1$$

It occurred to me that this can be proven without use of derivatives.  I wanted to check if my reasoning is valid or if there is an even easier algebraic argument.

(1) For $w \ge 6$, $2^w > \dfrac{w^2 +8w +16}{2}$ since:

- Base Case: $2^7 = 128 > 36+48+16 = 100$
- Assume $2^{w+1} > w^2+8w+16$
- $2^{w+2} > 2w^2 + 16w + 32 > (w+1)^2 + 8(w+1)+16 = w^2 + 10w +26$

(2) It follows that $n \ge 41$, $2^{\lfloor\sqrt{2n}-3\rfloor} \ge n$ since:

- Let $w = \lfloor\sqrt{2n} - 3\rfloor$ so that $w \ge 6$
- $\sqrt{2n} - 3< w+1$ so that $n < \dfrac{w^2 + 8w + 16}{2} < 2^w.$

Comment: It should be possible to do this use induction, and it would be more complicated to use derivative.

Comment: It looks fine to me except that I don't understand why you proved $2^w\gt\frac{w^2+8w+17}{2}$ instead of $2^w\gt\frac{w^2+8w+16}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying ti connect this with Bertrand’s Postulate.  I made several mistakes whichwhen I fixed resulted in the discrepancy.  I will change since there is no reason to keep it.